# Cinder can't update window's title when the application is running

Tags: c++, cinder

I have tried copying the Settings *settings to a class variable and using

```
sets->setTitle("new title");
```

but outside the setup() method it doesn't work. Is there a workaround to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everywhere in your app where you include the cinder app header

```
#include "cinder/app/AppNative.h"
```

You can call this to change the title, and other Window properties.

```
ci::app::getWindow()->setTitle("Respoducir Video");
```

---

## UPDATE - 15/12/2018

Cinder v0.9.1

The include path has changed to:

```
#include "cinder/app/Window.h"
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I knew window object was important for it, but I couldn't find a way to retrieve it. Thanks.